# Printing SharePoint Calendar with Color/Formatting

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-calendar, printing

I've been tasked with getting a SharePoint Calendar to print out direct from SharePoint.  I've proposed the "Add to Outlook" and print from Outlook method, which has been rejected.  Apparently the formatting is a necessary part of the printout, which does not translate over to Outlook.

I've looked online for a solution, and so far have only found this one:

http://www.boostsolutions.com/calendar-rollup.html

My preference is not to pay for something that should be doable, but I will if needed.

Are there any other methods that don't require a ton of coding knowledge, as I'm not a code guru.